# C precomputed expressions

Tags: c

I would like to switch processing in a library routine based on whether a parameter exceeds a function of a system limit or not, for example whether (input - 1) <= sqrt (LONG_MAX)

As I see it, I have three choices of implementing this in C:

1. evaluate the function in each library call. Expensive, though some compilers can probably optimise out math.h function calls with constant parameters
2. define the result of the function call as a preprocessor macro. Looking at glibc limits.h this would require two #defines based on the __WORDSIZE value. I don't think this would be portable
3. create a global variable that is set to the result of the function in an initialiser routine. This requires the library user to always run an init routine before any other library routines

I do not really like any of these approaches. A compromise between 1 and 3 would be to run the init internally if not run previously. This spares the user the need to do it and reduces the runtime overhead to one boolean value check.

Is there some more elegant solution possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Elegant" is not really a well defined term, you would have been better off specifying something more measurable, like "speed".

If speed is indeed the goal, an the system parameter is one that doesn't change at runtime, you can have a portable solution like:

```
#undef SQRT_LM
#if LONG_MAX == 64
    #define SQRT_LM 8
#endif
#if LONG_MAX == 256
    #define SQRT_LM 16
#endif
: : :
#ifndef SQRT_LM
    #error Weird LONG_MAX value, please adjust code above.
#endif
```

Then your code can simply use `SQRT_LM` as a constant value.

The `1/3` combo, along the lines of:

```
void doSomething(int x) {
    static long sqrt_lm = -1;
    if (sqrt_lm == -1)
        sqrt_lm = sqrt(LONG_MAX);
    // Now can use sqrt_lm freely
}
```

is not really as efficient as forcing the user to explicitly call an `init` function, since the above code still has to perform the `if` on every call.

But, as stated, it really depends on what you mean by "elegant". I tend to optimise for readability first and only worry about performance if it becomes a serious issue.

Comment: Good idea to check the values themselves rather than __WORDSIZE, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static variable in the function:

```
void foo(int input)
{
    static const long limit = __builtin_sqrt(LONG_MAX);

    assert(input < limit);
}
```

So `limit` is only computed the first time the function is executed.  This requires that the function is a constant expression, which is why I use GCC's `__builtin_sqrt()`; regular `sqrt()` will be rejected (by GCC, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't (input -1) <= sqrt(LONG_MAX) the same as input <= sqrt(LONG_MAX) + 1 which just looks like a simple compare of a value with a constant.